# How to know whether an username belongs to a group or a user in telegram using python? If yes, get the Group Title

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

I have tried with telethon but getting rate limited often / and with a sleep function, it's taking too long. Need something which works fast and doesn't get rate limited.

Comment: You cannot avoid "getting rate limited often". Checking by username is an expensive operation which Telegrams restricts a lot to prevent spam (among other reasons), and it is not possible to bypass it.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could do the following:

```py
async def check(name: str) -> str: # note, name could also be a list of usernames, it should be faster than just using one at a time
    try: 
        entity = await client.get_entity(name)
        if entity is Chat
            return entity.title
    except errors.FloodWaitError as error:
        asyncio.sleep(error.seconds)
        return await check(name)
    except Exception as e:
        print("Any other error, probably ValueError")
    return None
```

This will try to fetch the entity, if its successfull, then it will check if its a chat, if yes, it will return the title

If there is a FloodWaitError, it will wait the given seconds, and then check again, in any other case, it will return None

NOTE: I've said this by supposing you know well that you CAN'T avoid to get rate limited, and supposing you don't know the proper way to sleep, and you sleep way more than required.